# Making a costum iterable widget with ID on each item in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to make a costum star-based rating widget with different style of star on each usage

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class Stars extends StatelessWidget {
  const Stars({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: 
      [
      Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.yellow, size: 20,),
      Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.yellow, size: 20,),
      Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.yellow, size: 20,),
      Icon(Icons.star_outlined, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0xE1, 0xE1, 0xEA), size: 20,),
      Icon(Icons.star_outlined, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0xE1, 0xE1, 0xEA), size: 20,),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

the output UI will be like this
[image]

Is there any way I can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class RateStarIconRow extends StatelessWidget {
const RateStarIconRow({
    Key? key,
    this.totalStarCount = 5,
    required this.rateCount
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int totalStarCount;
  final int rateCount;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: List.generate(
        totalStarCount,
        (index) => Icon(
          Icons.star,
          color: index < rateCount ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And for the usage =>

RateStarIconRow(rateCount: 2)
```

Comment: I confirmed this solution worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can use somthing like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Main());
}

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  const Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stars(
            rate: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Stars extends StatelessWidget {
  final double rate;
  const Stars({
    required this.rate,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.star,
          color: rate >= 1 ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
          size: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.star,
          color: rate >= 2 ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
          size: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.star,
          color: rate >= 3 ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
          size: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.star_outlined,
          color: rate >= 4 ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
          size: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.star_outlined,
          color: rate == 5 ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
          size: 20,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You should get rate double from api and send to Stars Widget.

Comment: This soluton also work but i preferred solution from Kadir Bekar since it used iterable generate hence less boilerplate code